# Stop Kivy from ignoring exceptions

Tags: python, kivy

I've been using Kivy for quite a while now, and there's something that's been bothering me, but I couldn't find any useful information about it.

It happens sometimes that Kivy ignores exceptions.
This is making it really hard to track bugs when they happen.
Is there somewhere a way to stop Kivy from doing that?
It's not only catching its own exceptions but mine as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Joel

Comment: Can you please share a code snippet to clarify the case in which Kivy is ignoring exceptions?

Comment: I believe I am seeing the same behaviour and have filed [this bug](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5942)